# cake php saveAssociated not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm a new CakePHP user and i have some trouble using saveAssociated.
here's what i have:
**Models**

User model:      `$hasMany   = "Telephone";`
Telephone model: `$belongsTo = "User";`
**Controller**

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {

                if ($this->User->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
                   //success                      
                   return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
                //fail
            }
            // no data sent
        }
    }
```

**Data**

```
Array (
   [User] => Array (
            [name] => foo 
            [fname] => bar 
            [email] => foo@bar.com
   )
   [Telephone] => Array ( 
            [no] => 1 
            [num] => 0500000050  
   )
)
```

**Problem**

The User is created successfully with the id name fname and email.
The Telephone is added with only id and user_id ('no' and 'num' are not added).
Ps: i have tried "saveAll".
Please Help, Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `hasMany` the array should be in this form

```
array(
        'User' => array(
            'name' => 'Abhijeet Kambli',
            'fname' => 'Abhijeet',
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com'
         ),
        'Telephone' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'no' => '1',
                'num' => '999999999'
            )
        )
    )
```

so your `view/users/add.ctp` should be like this

```
<?php
        echo $this->Form->create('User'); 
        echo $this->Form->input('User.name');
        echo $this->Form->input('User.fname');
        echo $this->Form->input('User.email');
        echo $this->Form->input('Telephone.0.no');
        echo $this->Form->input('Telephone.0.num');

        echo $this->Form->submit('Add'); 
        echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

For second phone number

```
echo $this->Form->input('Telephone.1.no');
echo $this->Form->input('Telephone.1.num');
```

Comment: Thanks i guess i was doing it as if i had hasOne hasOne relation

Answer (score 2):

For `HasMany` associations the [correct format](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) is this:

```
'User' => array(
    'name' => 'foo',
    'fname' => 'bar',
    'email' => 'foo@bar.com'
),
'Telephone' => array(
    array(
        'no' => 1,
        'num' => '0500000050'
    )
)
```

Comment: It's not exactly in this way. That's correct whether you save it from belongsTo side, if you do it from hasMany Telephone is an array of arrays.